# React Hook useCallback not updating State value

Tags: reactjs, shopify, react-hooks

I'm new to React Hooks. I have a UI with multiple inputs with values in an object.  I create the UI with a loop, so I would like to have a single callback for the updating the inputs.

[image]

The "Shop" input uses it's own callback and successfully updates the state.  But the "Product" inputs never update the state. I don't really understand why these two callbacks behave differently.

The code is below.  The problem is in the `handleChange` callback.

```
import React, { useCallback, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { TextField, Form } from "@shopify/polaris";

export default function TextFieldExample() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    "prod-0": "Jaded Pixel",
    "prod-1": "blue diamonds"
  });
  const [shop, setShop] = useState("Joe's house of pancakes");

  const handleChangeShop = useCallback(newName => {
    setShop(newName);
  }, []);

  const handleChange = useCallback((newValue, id) => {
      console.log("Pre: values:", values);
      console.log(id, newValue);
      const newProds = values;
      newProds[id] = newValue;
      setValues(newProds);
      console.log("Post: newProds:", newProds);
    }, [values]);

  useEffect(() => {    // observing if State changes
    console.log("in useEffect: shop:", shop); // this gets called and is updated when changed.
    console.log("in useEffect: values:", values); // this never gets called or updated.
  }, [values, shop]);

  const items = [];
  Object.keys(values).forEach(function(prod) {
    items.push(
      <TextField label={"Product " + prod.substr(5)} id={prod} value={values[prod]} onChange={handleChange} />
    );
  });
  return (
    <Form>
      <TextField label="Shop" id="shop" value={shop} onChange={handleChangeShop}/>
      {items}
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Code Sandbox is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-tdd-1ip38
Try it out and look at the console.

Comment: You are mutating state `values` object instead of returning a new object reference.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are mutating the `values` state, see [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-dijkstra-vhn97) sandbox

Change your `handleChange` function to

```
const handleChange = useCallback((newValue, id) => {
  const newProds = { ...values };
  newProds[id] = newValue;
  setValues(newProds);
}, [values]);
```

You can change it further to

```
const handleChange = useCallback((newValue, id) => {
  setValues(prods => ({...prods, [id] : newValue }));
}, [values]);
```

Comment: I'm such an idiot!  Thank you! I was so focused on the "React-ness" and missed the obvious JS mess-up!

Answer (score 5):

Try updating `handleChange` to this:

```
const handleChange = useCallback(
    (newValue, id) => {
      console.log("Pre: values:", values);
      console.log(id, newValue);
      setValues(state => ({ ...state, [id]: newValue}));
    },
    [values]
  );
```

Comment: You do not need the `useCallback` in this situation

Answer (score 0):

An even more concise solution:

```
const handleChange = (newValue, id) => {
  setValues(prevState => ({...prevState, [id] : newValue}));
};
```

React state variables should never be modified directly.