# React: State not updating properly in a React component using "react-easy-crop"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, crop

I'm having trouble managing state in a React component that uses the `react-easy-crop` package. I store the crop state of the image in my component state and update it based on the user's actions.

The problem is, the crop coordinates **reset** to `{ x: 0, y: 0 }` every time the modal containing the image cropper is re-opened, even though I have saved the state with different values.

So, I set the state in the initial state in the parent component with data I get from the backend, then I drill it down in my EditPhotoModal component: imageUrl, crop, croppedArea, etc.

At the first open of the modal after a refresh, I am set correctly, but after I close the modal and reopen it again, I am always set to `{x: 0, y: 0}`, in the center of the page.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Cropper from 'react-easy-crop';
import { Point } from 'react-easy-crop/types';
import { IProfileImage } from './profile.types';

export const EditPhotoModal: React.FC<IEditPhotoModal> = ({
    image,
    openDialog,
    setCroppedImageFor,
    setOpenDialog,
    setCurrentImage,
    setPreviousImage,
    resetImage
}) => {
    const [crop, setCrop] = useState<Point>(image.crop);
    const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(image.zoom);

    useEffect(() => {
        setCrop({ x: image.crop!.x, y: image.crop!.y });
        setZoom(image.zoom || 1);

        if (image.croppedArea) {
            // Other operations 
        }
    }, [image.crop, image.zoom, image.croppedArea, openDialog]);

   const handleOnConfirm = useCallback(async () => {
        if (croppedAreaPixels && image.profileImageUrl) {
            try {
                const croppedImageUrl = await getCroppedImg(image.profileImageUrl, croppedAreaPixels);
                // Other operations 
                setCroppedImageFor(crop, zoom, croppedImageUrl);
                setPreviousImage((prev) => ({
                    ...prev,
                    croppedImageUrl: croppedImageUrl
                }));
            } catch (error) {
                // Error handling 
            }
        }
        setOpenDialog();
    }, [croppedAreaPixels]);

    return (
        <Dialog
            title={''}
            open={openDialog}
            onClose={onCloseModal}
            // Other props
        >
            {image.profileImageUrl ? (
                <Cropper
                    classes={{ cropAreaClassName: 'crop-area' }}
                    image={image.profileImageUrl}
                    crop={crop}
                    zoom={zoom}
                    aspect={aspect.value}
                    cropShape="round"
                    showGrid={false}
                    onCropChange={setCrop}
                    onZoomChange={setZoom}
                    onCropComplete={onCropComplete}
                />
            ) : (
                // Other JSX 
            )}
        </Dialog>
    );
};
```

In the parent component, I am passing down the **currentProfileImage **and **setCurrentProfileImage **as props to **EditPhotoModal**. Inside the **useEffect**, I am fetching the user's data (with **useUser**), and when it's available, I am initializing **currentProfileImage **with the user's profile photo URL, crop, and zoom parameters.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { IProfileImage } from './profile.types';  

export const SomeComponent = () => {
    const { userData, isLoading } = useUser();  // custom fetching hook with react-query
    
    const [currentProfileImage, setCurrentProfileImage] = useState<IProfileImage>(initialStateProfileCard);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (userData) {
            const { profilePhoto } = userData.profile;
            const initialUserCardData = {
                profileImageUrl: profilePhoto.url || '',
                crop: {
                    x: profilePhoto.cropParams.cropX,
                    y: profilePhoto.cropParams.cropY
                },
                zoom: profilePhoto.cropParams.zoom,
            };
            setCurrentProfileImage(initialUserCardData);
        }
    }, [userData]);

    const setCroppedImageFor = (crop: Point, zoom: number, croppedImageUrl: string) => {
        const newProfileImage = { ...currentProfileImage, crop, zoom, croppedImageUrl };
        setCurrentProfileImage(newProfileImage);
    };

    return (
        <EditPhotoModal
            openDialog={isEditPhotoModalOpen}
            setOpenDialog={() => setIsEditPhotoModalOpen(false)}
            image={currentProfileImage}
            setCurrentImage={setCurrentProfileImage}
            setCroppedImageFor={setCroppedImageFor}
            // rest of the props
        />
    );
};
```

Let me know if you need more context for it, I tried to be as explicit as possible

I also tried using a cropRef for storing the {x, y} values, but I got at the same end.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you are not actually saving the latest value to `setCroppedImageFor`.

You can try 2 things..

1. Remove useCallback & directly use the function `handleOnConfirm`
2. Can add more dependencies to function `handleOnConfirm`

```
   const handleOnConfirm = useCallback(async () => {
        if (croppedAreaPixels && image.profileImageUrl) {
            try {
                const croppedImageUrl = await getCroppedImg(image.profileImageUrl, croppedAreaPixels);
                // Other operations 
                setCroppedImageFor(crop, zoom, croppedImageUrl);
                setPreviousImage((prev) => ({
                    ...prev,
                    croppedImageUrl: croppedImageUrl
                }));
            } catch (error) {
                // Error handling 
            }
        }
        setOpenDialog();
    }, [croppedAreaPixels, crop, zoom, croppedImageUrl]).  // <<<< HERE ADD DEPS
```

Can also see: [React Hook useCallback not updating State value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60911179/react-hook-usecallback-not-updating-state-value)

Best of luck

Comment: Thanks for the response!

I did try your variant, it didn't seem to work as expected. Strange enough, the state in the parent component is being updated. When I log it in the child component, it is up to date.

But when trying to put it in the local state when opening the modal, the local "crop" is being set to {x: 0, y: 0}, maybe this is what I did not explain better.

Comment: As a way to work around this, I found that the EditPhotoModal is not rendering again. Which was okay in most of the cases where I needed a modal, but here it seems like I need it to mount and unMount, and I added a conditional render, and I did put the crop and setCrop functionality into the parent element as well:

{isEditPhotoModalOpen && (
                <EditPhotoModal ...props />
            )}

Which is working now.